# Deploying a Rails Application to an LAMP server with Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I just finished working on my first rails app and am ready to deploy to my VPS. I decided to try using Phusion Passenger and went through the extremely simple install process. I got all the right dependencies, so on that end things seems to be ok. Where I think my problem lies is in the routing and the apache config file.

As told I added the following at the very end of the following file: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/bl/gfy/public
    <Directory /home/bl/gfy/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I restart apache I get the following message:

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                        [Wed Aug 10 03:16:24 2011] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
 ... waiting [Wed Aug 10 03:16:26 2011] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

When I point my browser to my the IP I set up I get pointed to the sample file that comes with apache instead of to my rails app.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the ServerName to not be localhost? Let us know what happens.

Comment: @Thiago Jackiw I have tried to change the server name to the name of my app but that didn't work either. Also not I only have an IP for the server there isn't really a server name for me to specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Somewhat unrelated to your problem, but still.*

Both warning you see are not critical and should not affect server operations.
One means that your server hostname is not set, another just reminds you that passenger is already loaded from somewhere, probably after it stumbles upon in `/etc/apache/modules.d`.

All in all, you don't really want to edit `/etc/apache/apache2.conf`. Instead use existing structures, like `/etc/apache2/sites-available` etc.

*Now back to your problem.*

Your VirtualHost is most likely being overriden by default host.
Executing `sudo a2dissite default` in your shell will disable it. Assuming you don't have some exotic LAMP flavor.

Comment: thanks for the tip, now when I refresh it brings me to the public folder of my rails project but it is showing me the folder listing of the contents instead of running it as a rails app. Any further suggestions?

Comment: I assume you've fixed the issue already. If this is the case - could you please share some details. I'm sure other people will find it useful.

If it's not the case, you can try enabling [passenger logging](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerloglevel_lt_integer_gt). You'll have to check both general apache error log and site-specific one.

Comment: issue not solved yet, working on it later and will post some details as they become clear.

Comment: Check `/etc/apache2/modules.d` for mod_rails or passenger conf file. Check if [PassengerEnabled](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerenabled_lt_on_off_gt) is set to *off* there. If that's the case - either enable it globally (you'll need another file with higher preceding number in its name) or just for your virtualhost. I'd recommend going with the latter one, keeping things as small as possible is generally the best practice.

Comment: Actually instead of checking for a file you can use `grep -Ri PassengerEnabled /etc/apache2/`. The only downside is that you won't remember particular file names the next day :)

Comment: I used the grep command you just posted and it came back blank. I checked the /etc/apache2/ folder for the modules.d file couldn't find it either. In the /etc/apache2 folder I did noticed that two folders named mods-enabled mods-available but couldn't find the modules.d file anywhere. Appreciate all the help btw.

Comment: I also did a locate modules.d and came up with this: /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/modules.dep
/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/modules.dep.bin
/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/modules.devname
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/modules.d
/usr/share/man/man5/modules.dep.5.gz
Doesn't seem like I have what I need.

Comment: @Bnjmn let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2396/discussion-between-slotos-and-bnjmn)